# Maximize Utility

Tags: calculus, utility

I've looked through the site and researched but could not find any help on how to solve this: solve the following problem once with substitution and once with the Lagrange method

Max($x_1$* $x_2$) subject to $2x_1$ + $2x_2$ = 20

I'm not really even sure where to begin with the substitution or Lagrange method.  Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.  If you know the answer please post so I can work backwards and teach myself.  Thank you.

Comment: Example 3 [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/LagrangeMultipliers.aspx) is a 3-dimensional version of your problem with one additional constraint. If you read through that example and understand it, you will definitely be able to solve your problem using Lagrange multipliers. For the substitution method, just solve your constraint for (say) $x_1$ and plug that into your objective function. Now your problem is $\max((10-x_2)(x_2))$... find the argmax and then use the constraint to find the corresponding $x_1$.

Comment: It may be of pedagogical interest to solve it using those two methods, but still worth noting that the problem can be easily reduced to the case $x_{1,2} \ge 0\,$, then it follows from AM-GM that $\sqrt{x_1 x_2} \le \frac{1}{2}(x_1+x_2)=5\,$ with equality iff $x_1=x_2=5\,$.

Answer (score 2):

**Substitution**: use the constraint to get $x_2 = 10-x_1$, then replace in the objective function to have 
$$\max (10-x_1)x_1$$
This is a concave function, so first-order condition is necessary and sufficient. Equate first derivative to zero and find $x_1^*=5$. Replace this in constraint and obtain $x^*_2=5$. Then $(x^*_1,x^*_2)$ is the solution.

**Lagrange method**: write the Lagrangian
$$L= x_1x_2 - \lambda(x_1+x_2 -10)$$
The problem can be solved using first-order conditions (I am skipping details, but it can recasted as concave programming). Equate the derivatives of the Lagrangian w.r.t. to $x_1,x_2$ to zero and add the constraint to obtain a system of three equations in the three unknowns $x_1,x_2, \lambda$:
$$x_2-\lambda =0\\ 
x_1 - \lambda = 0\\
x_1+x_2=10$$
and solve this to get $x^*_1=x^*_2=\lambda^*=5$.